# Java CDI @ApplicationScoped sync/async access

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, concurrency, containers, cdi

I'm looking for a while and can't figure out how CDI container treats `@ApplicationScoped` bean. I mean - if you have class `Session` like:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Session {

    Map<User,Session> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(User user,Session session) {
        sessions.put(user,session);
    }

    public Session getSession(User user) {
        return list.get(user);
    }

}
```

The method `addSession(Session session, User user)` is called each time user is logged in. Suppose we want to retrieve from time to time user's session - we can do that through call `getSession(User user)` method.

The questions are:

1. If some call is putting `Session` and `User` to the map. Do other calls are suspended until the first putting call is finished? (for example we have additional, simutaneous 4 calls - 2 for `getSession` method and 2 for `add` methods)
2. If some call is trying to `getSession`. Do other simultaneous calls are also suspended until it finished?
3. Does `SynchronizedList` and/or `AtomicInteger` (suppose we have list of Integers, because that specific situation is only an example) changed something with it?

The main topic of that question is that: does `@ApplicationScoped` can really "freeze" my application? Because I feel it is a real bottleneck since I can't use `@ConcurencyManagement` locks like in EJB.

Answer (score 3):

Methods on a CDI bean can be accessed concurrently. No lock, no bottleneck, but you'll probably have reentrance issues with your code.

Methods on a @ApplicationScoped bean must be stateless or access to thread safe attributes : in your case you should change the HashMap to a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that. But I wanted to confirm that. You have no bottleneck but also need to deal with concurrently access.